# How to automatically install dev cluster libraries on a running production cluster in Azure databricks?

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

What is the best practice in automatically installing dev cluster libraries on a running production cluster in Azure databricks?

I found a certain solution of notebook-scoped libraries but I want to retain the libraries on the cluster and not have to update the notebooks libraries each time.

Comment: I found the solution. I will be using databricks CLI on the release pipeline.

Comment: Can you please explain how to install using CLI from release pipeline?